# Retornar foco no primeiro input

Tags: javascript, html

Possuo dois elementos `<input/>` no meu formulário.

```js
<form>
  <fieldset name="input-data">
    <label for="input-weight">Peso (KG):</label>
    <input
      id="input-weight"
      type="number"
      step="0.1"
      value="100"
      tabindex="1"
    />
    <label for="input-height">Altura (m):</label>
    <input
      id="input-height"
      type="number"
      step="0.01"
      value="1.90"
      tabindex="2"
    />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Gostaria de saber como retornar ao primeiro
`<input/>` quando acionar a tecla `Tab` no ultimo `<input/>` do formulário

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Adicionei no segundo `<input/>` no HTML

```html
<input
  id="input-height"
  type="number"
  step="0.01"
  value="1.90"
  tabindex="2"
  onfocus="changeTabIndex(true)"
  onblur="changeTabIndex(false)"
/>
```

No JavaScript criei a função

```js
function changeTabIndex(foco) {
  const inputWeight = document.getElementById('input-weight');
  if (foco) {
    inputWeight.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
  } else {
    inputWeight.setAttribute('tabindex', '1');
  }
}
```

Não sei se é a melhor forma, porem esta funcionando no momento.

Answer (score -2):

Basta você trocar os valores do tabindex, no primeiro input o tabindex deve ter o valor 0, no segundo input ele deve ter o valor 1, fazendo isso vai funcionar do jeito que você quer, vou deixar aqui a mudança para você ver.

```html
<form>
  <fieldset name="input-data">
    <label for="input-weight">Peso (KG):</label>
    <input
      id="input-weight"
      type="number"
      step="0.1"
      value="100"
      tabindex="0"
    />
    <label for="input-height">Altura (m):</label>
    <input
      id="input-height"
      type="number"
      step="0.01"
      value="1.90"
      tabindex="1"
    />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Dessa forma no primeiro `<input/>` quando dou Tab ele vai direto para a barra superior do navegador, porem do segundo input ele volta para o primeiro, desenvolvi uma função simples em JS para resolver isso, não sei se é a mais performática mas esta funcionando.

Comment: entendi, vi ali como você fez, se tá funcionando então ta ótimo.

Answer (score -3):

fiz isso e resovel

Aceitar Pedido
  Cancelar Pedido
  Fechar


  const modalFooter = document.querySelector('.modal-footer');
  const buttons = modalFooter.querySelectorAll('button');

  modalFooter.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Tab') {
      if (e.shiftKey) { // Se pressionar Shift + Tab
        if (document.activeElement === buttons[0]) {
          e.preventDefault();
          buttons[buttons.length - 1].focus();
        }
      } else { // Se pressionar apenas Tab
        if (document.activeElement === buttons[buttons.length - 1]) {
          e.preventDefault();
          buttons[0].focus();
        }
      }
    }
  });